# How to define the type of a member of an iterator class to work with STL container methods?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, type-conversion

I wish to define an iterator class over a vector, and how can its private member `p` match the return type of std::vector::begin()?

```
class A{

struct element{
      ...
}

  class e_iterator {

  e_iterator() : p()

    ...

    private:
      element* p;  
  };

  e_iterator e_begin() const{
     e_iterator Iter;
     Iter.p = e_.begin(); // error
     return Iter;
  }

 std::vector<element> e_;
```

}
I receive an error with `element* p`:

```
error: cannot convert 'std::vector<element, std::allocator<element>>::const_iterator' to 'element*' in assignment
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do and achieve?

Comment: @AndyProwl: `e_` is obviously `std::vector<element> const &`.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [boost.iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html).

Comment: Your function call `e_.begin()` returns a `const_iterator` (this is what your compiler seems to say), and `Iter.p` is a **non-`const`** pointer to `element`. Therefore, the conversion cannot be performed even if the iterator type returned by `begin()` is a pointer.  Anyway, an iterator of `std::vector<>` is *not* guaranteed to be a pointer, although in most implementations it will be.

Comment: Sorry about the ambiguity. `element` is a struct, and defined in std::vector<element> e_.

Comment: @Pippi Can you provide the real code? Your `e_begin` function is marked `const` but doesn't seem to be a member function. Is it supposed to be a member of some class?

Comment: e_begin is a member function of a class A. Class A has a vector of `element`, and an iterator class over the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With what you've given, the most I can suggest is changing `p` to:

```
std::vector<element>::const_iterator p;
```

The simple fact is that a `std::vector` iterator is not a pointer (probably). It is an unspecified type that behaves like a pointer - it meets the requirements of a Random Access Iterator.

When you call `begin()` on a non-`const` container, you get an `iterator` type. When you call it on a `const` iterator, you get a `const_iterator` type. Since your `a_begin` member function is marked `const` and `e_` appears to be a `std::vector<element>` member of your class, `e_` is transitively `const`, so calling `begin()` on it will also get you a `const_iterator`.

But it's quite hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do here and whether this is the right way to go about it.

Comment: "When you call begin() on a non-const iterator" you mean container?

Answer (score 1):

Either change `element* p` to `const element* p` in your iterator class or remove the const qualifier from your e_begin() method.
Or provide both const/non-const iterator. I also suggest to initialize the pointer in the iterator constructor:

```
template <bool isconst>
class e_iterator_ {

  public:
    typedef std::conditional<isconst, const element*, element*>::type elementptr;

    e_iterator_(elementptr e) : p(e)

  ...

  private:
    elementptr p;  
};

typedef e_iterator_<true> const_e_iterator;
typedef e_iterator_<false> e_iterator;
```

Then you could use the `data()` member method of std::vector to directly access the underlying array of the vector.

```
  e_iterator e_begin() const{
     const_e_iterator Iter(e_.data());
     return Iter;
  }
```

Hope this helps.